# Boolean expression into java

Tags: java, logic, boolean-logic

After creating a truth table I have arrived at the following expression

```
B(AC + aC + Ac) (lowercase represents NOT..meaning a means NOT A)
```

Is it possible to represent this in java without actually expanding this expression? Meaning without writing something like this?

```
if(B&&A&&C || B&&a&&C || B&&A&&c)
```

Comment: Why expanding? What's wrong with the direct translation `if( B && (A && C || !A && C || A && !C))`??? And, how come you didn't come up with `B(A+C)`?

Comment: @Bagana: There was nothing wrong with direct translation. I was just curious. And I'm just picking up server side programming so I'm still getting to the point where I can figure it out easily :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your notation correctly, since the complement of `AC + aC + Ac` is `ac`,  this expression can be simplified to

```
if (B && !(a && c))
```

which is equivalent to

```
if (B && (A || C))
```